# How to stop centering the map region to user's current location after user pans/moves the map

Tags: swift3, mkmapview, mapkit, userlocation

I have an app that displays a mapView, sets region and centers it to the  user's current location. It also displays various annotations. When a user drags/pans the map the `didUpdate userLocation` causes the region of the map to re-center to the user's current location which makes it impossible to pan the map. What is the best approach to `stopUpdating` the region? I tried to set `distanceFilter` but it didn't really work. I am not sure how to implement Bool iVar that some tutorials talk about. The code that I have is :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        region.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02
        myMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the current delegate method in favor of using a `CLLocationManager`. Then, if you need to set the map view's region, you can use the location received from the `CLLocationManager` instance in `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`. If you don't want to update the centering of the user's location on the map, then you could just set it once and then use the location however you intend.